# I'm travelling near the speed of light. Do I need to brake before using a super-massive black hole to turn around?

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, estimation, rocket-science, geodesics

I'm taking one of those new fusion drives for a trip to nearby supermassive black hole.  At a comfortable 1 G, it'll take me about 7 months of proper time to accelerate to 95% the speed of light.  I'm wondering, though, if I need to decelerate when I use the star's gravity to turn around and come home.  My first thought was that whipping around a star at 0.95c would create forces that would liquefy me and my crew.

My second thought was: this is a geodesic; even though we're completely reversing direction in a few microseconds, it will be just like floating in space.

Which is right? Do I need to brake for such a maneuver?

Comment: I doubt you'd be traveling along a geodesic. Those don't make 180 turns.

Comment: @rubenvb geodesics in spacetime certainly can make 180 degree turns when projected into space

Comment: Problem 1: at 0.95 *c*, you'll fly straight past Deneb with only the slightest deviation.  Only a black hole offers the kind of spacetime curvature you're thinking of. Problem 2: If your ship starts heading back to Earth then it has decelerated to zero. If you do that in less than 7 months then you'll experience more than 1 G. If you do it in microseconds it means you've smashed into a planet.

Comment: @Chappo - Thanks.  I'll make the edit about the black hole, but I don't understand your argument about decelerating to zero.  As I see it, after my initial burn, I don't experience any acceleration or deceleration, not even when whipping about the event horizon of a black hole.

Comment: How can you turn and come back without decelerating?

Comment: @Alchimista - Same way the moon circles the Earth without accelerating.

Comment: It's an intriguing idea - using a deep gravity well to reverse direction at near-light-speed. Since a geodesic is a straight line in curved space, there'd be no "deceleration". Perhaps a carefully calculated approach to a binary pair of BHs, with each providing a 90º turn?

Comment: The moon is not coming from out space and by the way is accelerated. Geodesic or not it is not the point as for GR doesn't kill netwonian law. You were to accelerate comfortably at 1g for seven month so at least to get the same level of comfort you must invert direction in a comparable period of time. Whatever the force is. Perhaps you can calculate a trajectory so that the BH will do exactly that. But I am not competent to answer that.

Comment: @rubenvb: the international space station is travelling on a geodesic.  It makes a 180-degree turn every 46 minutes or so.

Comment: @Alchimista - Yes, I'm afraid GR does replace Newtonian Laws.  In Newton's Universe, the moon is constantly accelerating as it travels around the Earth.  In Einstein's Universe, the moon is travelling in a straight line at a constant velocity.  There is no "Gravitational Force" in Einstein's universe.

Comment: @tfb yes but the space station (part of it) surely brakes to come back!

Comment: @Alchimista: no.  It's travelling on a geodesic: that's a curve in spacetime on which there is no acceleration.

Comment: I wasn't saying that GR doesn't replace Newton laws. I said it doesn't kill them. But I see know. Back home is just referred to the turning which is indeed a free fall. Back home meant near Earth not landing :))

Comment: Leaving aside the "getting killed by stuff in the accretion disk" bit, your injection window for making the turn you *want* is vanishingly small.

Comment: @dmckee - Possibly a topic for another discussion, but if you're travelling near the speed of light and the accretion disk is, say, 1AU, that means a total of 8 + 8 = 16 minutes of exposure (less if you factor in time dilation).  So is the radiation immediately around the black hole really a deal-killer?  If there's no acceleration when I turn, couldn't I just boost my speed to 99% the speed of light and make the trip around the black hole in a few seconds?

Comment: @DonaldAirey The problem isn't a diffuse radiation field; it is the matter particles in your way. Assuming only solar system densities and a ship presenting only $100 \mathrm{m}^2$ of frontal area, you hit around 25 micromoles of hydrogen in a 2 AU passage. The kinetic energy is $14 GJ$ (and of course the high Lorentz factor make the power dissipation issue *worse*), and $DIETY help you if you hit a dust grain. OF course you face this problem in interstellar space as well, but it gets much more intense in higer matter density regions.

Comment: @dmckee oops, hadn't read Dan Yand's answer. Sorry - deleting my comment...

Comment: @dmckee - Yes, I agree that anything baryonic would make the trip less comfortable.  I suspect at some point just the friction from Hydrogen would be an issue.  If radiation isn't the problem, then we'll dial this back to 95% the speed of light.  I believe that dramatically cuts down on the kinetic issues without changing the travel time much.

Answer (score 5):

> My first thought was that whipping around a star at 0.95c would create forces that would liquefy me and my crew.

This is not correct, but there is a different problem that will likely prove fatal anyway.

> My second thought was: this is a geodesic; even though we're turning around 180 degrees in a few microseconds, it will be just like floating in space.

This is closer to correct, but it has two serious problems: first is the size of the orbit required, and the second is the tidal forces involved.

Regarding the size of the orbit: in order to make a turn around at 0.95 c will require an orbit which passes exceptionally close to the central object.  For an object as large as a star you will not orbit outside the object but you will instead crash into the star itself.  The only objects which are sufficiently compact for you to pass that close are black holes.  This will require knowledge of your orbit and the black hole's position and motion to extreme precision.  Slightly too far away and your trajectory will barely deflect, and slightly too close and you will cross the event horizon.

Regarding the tidal forces: tidal forces are roughly proportional to $1/r^3$.  As you indicated above, for a point particle traveling along a geodesic is quite peaceful.  However, your ship and crew are not point particles.  The difference in forces will be enormous.  The parts of the ship on the inside of the turn will be making the 180 degree turn, while the parts of the ship on the outside of the turn will be barely deflected and continue on at nearly 0.95 c in nearly a straight line.

The only possible solution would be to find a supermassive black hole to turn around. That will reduce both of the above problems. (Or slow down)

Comment: I think the idea of moving along s geodetic in spacetime is not as to be used to neglect acceleration.  The crew will be subject to g forces the entity of which will depend on the calculated trajectory assuming one exists that brings the ship back.  Plus tidal forces as you said.

Comment: In layman words a trajectory along a path in spacetime isn't a trajectory in space. Am I right? Else everyone knowing GR would go to a pilot centrifuge like drinking water. :)

Comment: @Alchimista the g forces experienced by an object can be measured using an accelerometer.  When an accelerometer is in free fall it reads 0, in other words if you are being accelerated by gravity then you are not subject to g forces.  As long as the ship and the crew are small enough that tidal forces are negligible there will be no g forces in free fall regardless of the acceleration. This is the difference between "proper acceleration" and "coordinate acceleration"

Comment: There is a lot of inaccuracy in this answer. You do not need to go right outside  the event horizon to make a U-turn at a black hole. You need to be a short distance outside the photon sphere (1.5 $\times$ the Schwarzschild radius). And your description of the tidal forces (barely deflected vs.180 degree turn) are inaccurate for a solar-size black hole, unless your spaceship is many kilometers long. The tidal forces will be big enough to kill you, though, unless the black hole is supermassive.

Answer (score 5):

> Do I need to brake before using a star to turn around?

What kind of star? If the star is sufficiently compact, like neutron star or black hole, then *no*, you don't need to brake, and you'll be in free-fall the whole time. (Well, you might get fried by whatever plasma and electromagnetic fields are being slung around by the neutron star / black hole, but let's just consider *gravitational* effects here. No accretion disk, no astrophysical jets.)

As [Dale's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/451881/206691) explained,  if the black hole is large enough, then tidal effects will be negligible, so the ride will be comfortable — if remaining weightless qualifies as "comfortable." A supermassive black hole should work quite nicely.

To make this a little more quantitative, first consider the simplest scenario: an ideal non-rotating black hole. Let $R$ denote the Schwarzschild radius, which is where the event horizon is. Light can orbit this black hole; the simplest orbit that light can have is a circular orbit, which necessarily has a radius of $3R/2$. And of course, if light can *orbit* the black hole, then the black hole can also be used to *slingshot* light. And if it can slingshot light, then it can certainly also slingshot something moving at 95\% of the spin of light.

You'll need to tune the approach carefully, though, because slight changes in your approach to the black hole can make surprisingly big differences in the outcome. But with careful tuning, you *can* reverse your direction by slingshotting around a black hole.

Of course, real black holes are most likely spinning very rapidly. In that case, the frame-dragging effect makes life much more interesting. Yes, you can still slingshot around a rapidly-spinning black hole, but you'll need to do some very careful calculations to make sure you end up where you want to, because geodesics in the neighborhood of a Kerr (spinning) black hole can be *crazy*.

For reference, first consider circular equatorial orbits for something moving at the speed of light. For a non-rotating black hole, the orbit must have radius $3R/2$, as mentioned above. The Schwarzschild radius in that case is $R=2M$, where $M$ is the black hole's mass (in natural units where Newton's constant and the speed of light are both equal to $1$), so the radius of the orbit can also be written $r=3M$. For a Kerr black hole that's spinning as fast as a black hole can possibly spin, the radius is either $r=M$ or $r=4M$ (equation 4.49 in "Geodesics of the Kerr metric", http://www.roma1.infn.it/teongrav/leonardo/bh/bhcap4.pdf), depending on whether the orbit is prograde or retrograde. This extreme difference between the photon-orbit radii in the prograde and retrograde cases is a testament to just how large the frame-dragging effects can be.

Those radii are for *circular obrits* moving at the *speed of light*, but the fact that such orbits exist implies that something moving at 95\% of the speed of light can use the black hole as a slingshot, as long as the distance of closest approach is suitably increased. And again, we're talking about geodesics here, so you'll remain comfortably(?) in free-fall the whole time, if the black hole is large enough to avoid uncomfortable tidal effects.

That's for *equatorial* geodesics. For non-equatorial geodesics, things get really wonky. For example, figure 4.25 in O'Neill's book *The Geometry of Kerr Black Holes* shows a "timelike flyby polar orbit that meets the Axis four times." The interactive website https://duetosymmetry.com/tool/kerr-circular-photon-orbits lets you construct examples of non-equatorial photon orbits, which illustrates just how careful you'll need to be with your calculations before attempting to use a spinning black hole as a slingshot (unless you're one of those people who thinks the journey is more important than the destination). But if it takes you $7$ months of proper time to accelerate to the desired speed, then I suppose you'll have plenty of free time to double-check those calculations.

Related:

https://space.stackexchange.com/q/530

https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1911